# The instance of entity type cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for { 'ID'} is already being tracked

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Good night, How are you?

I am developing an app which includes entity framework in .NET 7, I have the following problem:

I have the Voucher entity, which has a list of VouchersDetails, to which if I want to add details to this Voucher (VouchersDetails) it throws me the following error:

```
The instance of entity type cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for { 'ID'} is already being tracked.
```

Does anyone know why this is? I leave you the code:

Clarification: I am manually modifying the status of the Entry, here I leave the code.

Sqlite Injection:

```
 public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructureServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {

        services.AddDbContextFactory<SqliteStoreCustomersContext>(opt =>
        {
            opt.UseSqlite
            (
                $"{ProjectConfig.DatabasePath}"
            );
           
        });

        #region [PRODUCTS]
        services.AddScoped<IProductRepository, SqliteProductRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IProductBarCodeRepository, SqliteProductBarCodeRepository>();
        #endregion

        #region [EMPLOYEES]

        services.AddScoped<IEmployeeRoleRepository, SqliteEmployeeRoleRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IEmployeeRepository, SqliteEmployeeRepository>();
        #endregion

        #region [PRICE LISTS]
        services.AddScoped<IPriceListRepository, SqlitePriceListRepository>();
        #endregion

        #region [BRANCHS OFFICES]
        services.AddScoped<IBranchOfficeRepository, SqliteBranchOfficeRepository>();
        #endregion

        #region [VOUCHERS]
        services.AddScoped<IVoucherRepository, SqliteVoucherRepository>();
        #endregion

        return services;
    }
```

Generic Sqlite Repository:
This is where I manually modify the state of the Entry. The method is: entityStateModifiedManually

```
namespace Infrastructure.EntityFramework.Persistence.Shared;
public class SqliteRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : BaseModel, IAggregateRoot
{
    protected readonly StoreCustomersContext<SqliteStoreCustomersContext> contexto;

    public SqliteRepository(StoreCustomersContext<SqliteStoreCustomersContext> contexto)
    {
        this.contexto = contexto;
    }

    protected DbSet<T> setearEntidad => contexto.Set<T>();

    public async Task<T> Save(T entidad)
    {
        try
        {
            T result;
            await entityStateModifiedManually(entidad);
            if (contexto.Entry(entidad).State == EntityState.Detached || contexto.Entry(entidad).State == EntityState.Added)
                result = (await contexto.AddAsync(entidad)).Entity;
            else
                result = entidad;

            await contexto.SaveChangesAsync();

            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }



    public async Task<List<T>> GetAll()
    {
        return await setearEntidad.ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<IReadOnlyList<T>> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return await setearEntidad.Where(predicate).ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<IReadOnlyList<T>> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, string includeString = null, bool disableTracking = true)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = contexto.Set<T>();
        if (disableTracking) query = query.AsNoTracking();

        if (predicate != null) query = query.Where(predicate);

        if (orderBy != null) return await orderBy(query).ToListAsync();

        return await query.ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<IReadOnlyList<T>> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, List<Expression<Func<T, object>>> includes = null, bool disableTracking = true)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = contexto.Set<T>();
        if (disableTracking) query = query.AsNoTracking();

        if (includes != null) query = includes.Aggregate(query, (current, include) => current.Include(include));

        if (predicate != null) query = query.Where(predicate);

        if (orderBy != null) return await orderBy(query).ToListAsync();

        return await query.ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<T> GetById(int id)
    {
        return await setearEntidad.FindAsync(id);
    }

    public async Task<T> GetById(int id, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return await setearEntidad.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id.Equals(id));
    }

    public async Task<T> GetById(int id, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, string includeString = null, bool disableTracking = true)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = contexto.Set<T>();
        if (disableTracking) query = query.AsNoTracking();

        if (predicate != null) query = query.Where(predicate);

        if (orderBy != null)
            return await orderBy(query).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id.Equals(id));

        return await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id.Equals(id));
    }

    public async Task<T> GetById(int id, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, List<Expression<Func<T, object>>> includes = null, bool disableTracking = true)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = contexto.Set<T>();
        if (disableTracking) query = query.AsNoTracking();

        if (includes != null) query = includes.Aggregate(query, (current, include) => current.Include(include));

        if (predicate != null) query = query.Where(predicate);

        if (orderBy != null) return await orderBy(query).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id.Equals(id));

        return await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id.Equals(id));
    }

    public async Task<T> Delete(int id)
    {
        T entidad = await setearEntidad.FindAsync(id);
        setearEntidad.Remove(entidad);
        await contexto.SaveChangesAsync();
        return entidad;
    }

    public async Task<T> Delete(T entity)
    {
        setearEntidad.Remove(entity);
        await contexto.SaveChangesAsync();
        return entity;
    }

    #region [ADDITIONAL METHODS]
    private async Task entityStateModifiedManually(object ObjectToRecurse)
    {
        contexto.ChangeTracker.TrackGraph(
        ObjectToRecurse, node =>
        {
            var PrimaryKey = node.Entry.Property($"Id");
            var keyValue = (int)PrimaryKey.CurrentValue;

            if (keyValue == 0)
                node.Entry.State = EntityState.Added;
            else if (keyValue < 0)
                node.Entry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
            else
            {
                var item = setearEntidad.Find(keyValue);
                if (item == null)
                {
                    node.Entry.State = EntityState.Added;
                }
                else
                {
                    node.Entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
            }

        });

        return;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Method which calls the generic repository

```
 public async Task<int> AddVoucherDetail(int voucherId,VoucherDetail voucherDetail)
 {
     try
     {
         var voucherFound = await voucherSearcher.GetVoucherByIdAsync(voucherId);

         if (voucherFound == null)
         {
             throw new VoucherFoundNull();
         }

         voucherFound.AddDetail(voucherDetail);

         await voucherRepository.Save(voucherFound);

         return 1;
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
         throw ex;
     }
 }
```

Comment: This is likely caused by your GenericRepo calling 'query.AsNotTracking' somewhere. Reading+changing an entity that is retrieved with '.AsNotTracking' and then calling save on it would cause exactly that error

Comment: Don Quixote assistant is right. You will need to share the concrete implementation of the GetVoucherByIdAsync method to be certain. But, you are probably missing a (disableTracking: false) inside of that method when calling the generic repository method GetById.

Comment: Thank you very much guys, I was putting "DisableTracking" in the GetById method, this solved that problem, the problem is that based on this resolution now I get the following error:

{Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
  ---> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 19: 'UNIQUE constraint failed: vouchers_details.Id'.

I was looking to try not to disturb but I don't know what it could be